# How to retrieve files in creation oder using scandir

Tags: c, scandir

I would like to use a C API to read files in a directory in creation order, but I know that `readdir()` does not specify a read order.  So I can use `scandir()` to do this, by passing a compare function that would do a `stat()` on the 2 `d_name` fields of the `struct dirent` and return `-1`, `0` or `1` to determine which entry was created first.

But I have 2 questions:

1. `struct dirent` has a `d_ino` field. Can I get the creation time using the `d_ino` field more efficiently than calling `stat()`?
2. The function signature for the compare function is `int compare(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **);`  It seems like passing the structs by a `const` pointer instead of a `const` double pointer would be sufficient.  Does anyone know why the structs are passed by a double pointer instead of just by a pointer?

Comment: The answer to 2 is that `scandir` creates an array of pointers, and then sorts the array of pointers. So the `compare` function gets a pointer that points to an entry in the array (which happens to be a pointer).

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to retrieve the creation time from the inode directly.

In order to minimize the number of `stat()` system calls follow these steps:

- allocate an array of structures with the creation time and the pointer to the file name.
- initialize this array by calling `stat()` iteratively for each entry, composing the full filename from the entry and the relative path from the current directory, and store the creation time and the pointer to the entry name.
- sort this array with an ad-hoc sorting function.
- list the entries from this table.

Comment: Thanks. So I think you are suggesting that I 1) pass NULL as the compare function to scandir(), which would then return the number of filtered struct dirent entries; and then 2) follow your 4 steps above. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. that is my suggestion. Note however that it will only improve speed on very large directories. Benchmarking will tell you if it is worth the trouble.